# How to retrieve AD account permissions in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap, coldfusion-10

I know I can't be the only one who's needed to do this, but I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this in ColdFusion. I need to check the permissions for an Active Directory service account against a user object's attributes. From what I've read, I'll need to retrieve the constructed attribute "allowedAttributesEffective", but that returns an empty string when used in CFLDAP. I'm using a base scope, which is required, according to [this site](http://www.selfadsi.org/deep-inside/attribute-constructed.htm), but to no avail. Any insight as to how I'll be able to accomplish this?

Since code was requested... I don't have access to the exact code this weekend, but following is an estimation of it. Note that I don't remember the exact port I'm using; don't know if that would make a difference, unless the global catalog doesn't support allowedAttributesEffective.

Edit: I was using port 3268, which is the port for the Global Catalog. I switched to 389, but still having the same issue.

```coldfusion
<cfldap 
   server = "#server_name#"
   port = "389"
   username = "#serviceAccount.userName#"
   password = "#serviceAccount.password#"
   action = "query"
   filter = "userprincipalName=#my.upn#"
   name = "name"
   start = "#my.dn#"
   scope = "base"
   attributes = "allowedAttributesEffective">

<cfdump var='#name#'>
```

Comment: Can you include the <cfldap> code you are using?

Comment: Did you try specifying a `filter` attribute? `filter="(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=#uid#))"`

Comment: What are you using for your start attribute?

Comment: The DN of my personal user object.

Comment: Oh and I am using a filter, "userprincipalname=#my.upn#". Added this to the code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code is fine, but the service account I am using is returning that attribute as empty, despite the fact it has rights to pretty much every attribute. When I run this code using my own account it works correctly. This isn't a ColdFusion issue but more of an Active Directory issue. Haven't resolved it yet but the code side works perfectly.